# GPU Frame Capture is "Not Available" On Simulator?

Tags: xcode, metal

I'm trying to enable GPU Frame Capture, but the dropdown says "Not Available" when I have any iOS simulator device selected as the build target on a new SwiftUI project.

[image]

Does GPU Frame Capture not work on the simulator? I'm on Xcode 11.1 and I didn't see anything about the simulator mentioned in the docs:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/frame_capture_debugging_tools

Comment: In general nothing involving the GPU works in the simulator. Until Xcode 11 Metal didn’t work in the simulator and even now it’s buggy. What you’re describing doesn’t seem at all surprising.

Answer (score 1):

This is available in more recent versions of Xcode (eg v12).